# Is it possible that two 1-D Normal distributions, with equal mean and variance, can have different shapes?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I was going through the definition of Kurtosis and there I found that it is possible that given two 1D normal distributions with the same mean and variance, they can have a different shapes. I found this concept counter-intuitive, as the normal distribution is governed by mean & standard deviation?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your intuition is correct.  A 1D normal distribution always has a kurtosis=3.  Other 1D distributions will have different values of kurtosis depending on the specific shape of that distribution, but they won't be normal.  More details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis

I hope this helps.